# How do I make vaadin do not show scrollbars (when using setSizeFull for main layout)

Tags: java, vaadin

Given the following vaading example app:

```
package net.kerba.vaadin7interface;

import com.vaadin.annotations.Theme;
import com.vaadin.annotations.VaadinServletConfiguration;
import com.vaadin.server.VaadinRequest;
import com.vaadin.server.VaadinServlet;
import com.vaadin.shared.ui.label.ContentMode;
import com.vaadin.ui.*;

import javax.servlet.annotation.WebInitParam;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;

/**
 * Created by IntelliJ IDEA.
 * Date: 19.11.13
 * Time: 20:48
 */

@Theme("runo")
public class MainUi extends UI {

    @Override
    protected void init(VaadinRequest request) {

        GridLayout main = new GridLayout();
        main.setSizeFull();
        main.setMargin(false);

        Panel panel = new Panel("Working area");
        main.addComponent(panel, 0, 0);

        // magic goes in 2 lines below
        panel.setWidth("500px");
        panel.setHeight("300px");

        panel.setContent(new Label("foobar");", ContentMode.PREFORMATTED));

        main.setComponentAlignment(panel, Alignment.MIDDLE_CENTER);
        setContent(main);
    }

    @WebServlet(name = "vaadinServlet",
            urlPatterns = {"/app/*", "/VAADIN/*"},
            asyncSupported = false,
            initParams = {@WebInitParam(
                    name = "widgetset",
                    value = "com.vaadin.DefaultWidgetSet"
            )}
    )
    @VaadinServletConfiguration(productionMode = false, ui = MainUi.class)
    public static class Servlet extends VaadinServlet {

    }
}
```

When I use % for width and height:

```
panel.setWidth("50%");
panel.setHeight("50%");
```

I get both scrollbars:

[image]

When I use pixels for width and height:

```
panel.setWidth("500px");
panel.setHeight("300px");
```

The both scrollbars are gone:

[image]

How can I use % for width and height and make Vaadin do not show that scrollbars?

Vaadin 7.1.8

Answer (score 1):

I've found that introducing your own theme by extending e.g. runo or reindeer always pays. Then having this you can declare a class on you `panel` and set its width/height in CSS rather than in the code. This way it's the browser which sets the size before any JS executes and so it's known before JS that scrollbars are not needed in this case.

Answer (score 1):

It's because with GridLayout writing

```
main.setComponentAlignment(panel, Alignment.MIDDLE_CENTER);
```

it sets in fact gridlayout-slot in the middle of the screen making it 100% size of your screen and from this 50% is your panel - for me it seems to be a bug...

The workaround would be to use different layout, with VerticalLayout it will work. Or fake grid layout with CustomLayout.

Comment: While a bug in Vaadin certainly seems like a charming explanation, I doubt it is actually true since the problem is far too common. Do you have actual proof or a plausible explanation for this assumption?

Comment: I think it's bug because setting panel in the center you expect to have the panel itself in the center, not slot div. So in my opinion slot should take whole browser window and panel should be centered inside of it.

Answer (score 0):

I am not very sure about the solution, but while referring online. I found a couple of links, which I think can help you solve the problem:

[Link 1](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/grid.html)

[Link 2](http://www.javabeginner.com/java-swing/java-gridlayout-class-example)

According to which

```
main.setComponentAlignment(panel, Alignment.MIDDLE_CENTER);
```

makes it to be in the middle of the screen i.e, actually half of the panel defined.

1. You can go about either creating another panel with different specifications or use a virtual view to work around with this, ie. A Grid Layout that would just be used to format the indents and customize it effectively to your use.
2. Use HGap, VGap and then set the alignment. Refer this [example](http://java.about.com/od/Layout_Managers/ss/Gridlayout-Example-Program.htm)
3. Use an entirely different layout completely, some change in the current specification for layout positioning.

Comment: The links you refer to talk about swing, but the question is about a Vaadin GridLayout.